# How can I see certain user's profile page on facebook?

Tags: android, facebook

I'd like to see certain user's profile page on facebook. I used the following code, but it didn't work. I just saw progress bar spinning on facebook app:

```
try{
            // open in Facebook app
            getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
            return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/" + facebookId));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // open in browser
            return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/" +facebookId));
        }
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
try{
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://profile/100000349415153"));
 startActivity(intent); 
}catch(Exception e){
 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/fahimsakri")));
 } 
}
```

Comment: I tried that already. But I saw error message like not available at Facebook app. Do you know why?

Comment: because the profile id is nvalid, try a valid profile id

Comment: Is the profile id same with facebook user id? I can see my profile page with the same id on web browser